# Why this string result un-wanted line spacing at unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

[image]

At the user's name part(middle), why user's name has one line blank?

I wrote code like

```
public void SetHighInfo()
{
    var high = HighScore.Instance; 
    rankText.text = "";
    nameText.text = "";
    scoreText.text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < high.scoreInfo.Count; i++)
    { 
        rankText.text += "" + high.scoreInfo[i].rank + "\n";
        nameText.text += high.scoreInfo[i].name+"\n";
        scoreText.text += "" + high.scoreInfo[i].score + "\n";
    } 
}
```

As above, I just used "\n" once at name part. But result shows like using twice \n.

Why? How to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `nameText`'s line spacing set differently than the other texts? Do the names already have `"\n"` by chance?

Comment: How's the structure of your UI elements set up, and what are their properties?

Comment: Also, why are you adding empty strings to rank and score?

Comment: Check your high.scoreInfo[i].name string. It may be too long and is wrapping. Try putting kim as all the variables in this array. See if the spacing persists.

Answer (score 0):

I checked original data itself has newline after name's end.

So code was like this, maybe feof, fgets took line changes.

```
<?php
function DeleteOld($table){ //Delete all entries from a table
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE $table"; //truncate keeps the structure of the sql table 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
}
function RePopulate($table,$names,$min,$max,$count){ //Repopulate With Dummy Entries
    //Repopulate table with '$count' number of entries
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
        $name = $names[mt_rand(0,Count($names) - 1)]; //Get a random name
        $score = floor(mt_rand($min,$max)); //Get a random score
        $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table(name,score,date)
        VALUES('$name','$score','$date')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
    }
    //Now update our table, by ordering it by descending score
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE $table ORDER BY score DESC,id DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

include('ServerConnect.php');
$connection = Connect();//Attempt to connect to MYSQL server & dataBase

//Get variables from user
$table = $_POST['table'];
$mode = $_POST['mode'];
$userCount = $_POST['count'];
$minScore = $_POST['min'];
$maxScore = $_POST['max'];

//Grab all good names we will use
if($mode == 'Reset'){
    $names[0] = 'Names Array';
    $index = 0;
    $file = fopen("GoodNames.txt","r") or exit("No Such File"); //Open goodnames.txt file
    while(!feof($file)){ //Read each line and Add
        $names[$index] = fgets($file); // add all names to an array
        $index++;
    }
}
DeleteOld($table); //Delete all entries from chosen table   
if($mode == 'Reset'){RePopulate($table,$names,$minScore,$maxScore,$userCount);} //Repopulate the table if we are in reset mode
echo 'Scores Reset';
?>
```